# How to disassociate a file type with an application in Mac OS

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, file-association, parallels

I have a Mac and I'm running Snow Leopard.  I also run parallels.  Now, because I opened a file with a windows application while in parallels, that file type is always associated with the windows application.  So, what that means is that if I click on the file while using the Mac OS, parallels and windows gets opened up which I don't want to happen.  How can I change the file type association?

Comment: Parallels and VMWare both offer settings somewhere in the program to disable that FTA linking crap. I have always recommended killing it for this reason, it is often too confusing and stupid to be useful.

Comment: @peelman, watch your blood pressure ;-)

Comment: I changed jobs about a month ago, my blood pressure has been much better since then, but thanks for your concern. :)

Answer (score 9):

This is what I did in Parallels Desktop 5.

1. Open Application: Parallels Desktop
2. Click Menu: Window/Virtual Machine List
3. Right Click: Virtual Machine
4. Select Pop-up Item: Configure
5. Select Tab: Options
6. Pick from List: Shared Applications
7. Uncheck: Share Windows Applications with Mac OS X
8. Optionally uncheck: Share Mac OS X applications with Windows.

I tested it with this command in Terminal:

```
open -a Firefox http://www.apple.com
```

Comment: This is the right answer. The other answer requires that you take that action for *every file type* you want to dissociate.

Comment: Q: how can I allow one and only one Guest (Windows) app to be associated (FrameMaker, the main reason I have purchased Parallels), but not any others?  (And still be able to use, e.g. Windows Outlook when I run into the shortcomings of host MacOS Outlook)?

Answer (score 3):

Right-click the file, select *Get Info*. In the *Open with* section, change the default application, and optionally click *Change All*. More info at this [tech-recipes article](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2573/os_x_how_to_change_default_application_to_open_file_type/).

[image: Example]